# Rails - gem instagram - issues on access token and sandbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instagram, access-token

I need to put on a website the complete instagram feed of my customer. I have tried several ways to access to instagram and get the whole feed, but I get some errors.

Using the gem "instagram" (the easiest and simplest method) i got the following error when I try to get the access token.

```
Instagram::BadRequest: POST https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token/: 400: OAuthException: Matching code was not found or was already used.
```

I tried to follow the indication on the instagram documentation https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/ using my browser and I can get the access token, but I am not able to do the http calls manually in ruby.

I need to download all the data and keep it inside my database (as I always done) so I need everything in the controller.

my code is very simple:

```
accessToken = Instagram.get_access_token(Instagram.client_id, :redirect_uri => CALLBACK_URL)
client = Instagram.client(access_token: accessToken)
response = client.user_recent_media

#other code to cycle inside posts and put everything in db
```

i'm sure to have included the same redirect_url in my instragram registration app and in my code.

Comment: Could you please restructure your question? I can't seem to understand what you need.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the sample application in [the gem's repo](https://github.com/facebookarchive/instagram-ruby-gem), you will need to call authorize_url first:

```
 Instagram.authorize_url(:redirect_uri => CALLBACK_URL)
```

and then you will get request on the `CALLBACK_URL`, where you should have an action with the code that you provided:

```
 response = Instagram.get_access_token(params[:code], :redirect_uri => CALLBACK_URL)
 client = Instagram.client(:access_token => response.access_token)    
 # do stuff with the client
```

Comment: Roberto Bob Bowldee, I see. Would you be able to provide a pastebin with the code in the methods, where you use the Instagram gem, routes.rb file and also the place that you configure the Instagram gem, so I can get better idea where the problem comes from. And just a note: on Stack Overflow, it's better to edit your question with more information, instead of adding new answers to the thread. :)

Comment: thanks Victor, sorry for that. no real code now I have to create a method in my model a method in order to create a task to be called once per day. The first step is to get the access token and connect to instagram: ---1. FROM MY MODEL: call the address given by `Instagram.authorize_url(:redirect_uri => CALLBACK_URL)` ---2. get the `param[:code]` from the response of this address ---3. put it in this => `Instagram.get_access_token(params[:code], :redirect_uri => CALLBACK_URL)` ---4. access the client with `Instagram.client(:access_token => response.access_token)` I am at step 1!

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!
I have misunderstood the usage of the api.

I got my access token following this https://elfsight.com/blog/2016/05/how-to-get-instagram-access-token/

and i can access my posts using in my model:

```
access_token  = Instagram.access_token
client = Instagram.client(access_token: access_token)
response = client.user_recent_media
```

and in my config file:

```
Instagram.configure do |config|
config.client_id     = "CLIENT_ID"
config.client_secret = "CLIENT_SECRET"
config.access_token  = "ACCESS_TOKEN"
end
```

thanks a lot for your support

Answer (score 0):

you should get the token when processing the callback in the omniauth.auth hash: request.env['omniauth.auth']['credentials']['token']